# Is there any restriction on the use of dji-sdk?

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to know that whether there is any restriction on the use of dji-sdk?

1. Does the api provided in the SDK have a limit on the number of accesses,
   is there a limit on the access time and is there a limit on access traffic?
2. Are the features provided by SDK completely free?
3. Can a mobile phone connect to multiple DJI devices?

Answer (score 0):

If you pay the subscription fee,  then there are no restrictions.   If you don't pay the subscription fee then you are limited to a few devices registering for SDK access.

Yes,  a single mobile device can connect to any supported DJI device and should work.   Connections to devices are not limited if you don't pay the subscription but you are still limited to the number if devices you can register until the subscription is paid.